# How to train YOLO (Darknet) on 16 bit depth image files?

Tags: neural-network, computer-vision, deep-learning, object-detection, darknet

The current implementation of yolo supports 8 bit depth, 3 channel png / jpg images to train on. I need to train yolo on 16 bit, 3 channel png images. What code do I need to change?

**I have currently changed the following code:**

In function `image load_image_stb(char *filename, int channels)`, changed:

- `unsigned char *data = stbi_load(filename, &w, &h, &c, channels);` to `unsigned short *data = stbi_load(filename, &w, &h, &c, channels);`
- `im.data[dst_index] = (float)data[src_index]/255.;` to `im.data[dst_index] = (float)data[src_index]/65536.;`

In function `image load_image_cv(char *filename, int channels)`, changed `src = cvLoadImage(filename, flag)` to `src = cvLoadImage(filename, -1)` since the `-1` flag asks opencv to load the image with original depth.

In function void `ipl_into_image(IplImage* src, image im)`, changed:

- `unsigned char *data = (unsigned char *)src->imageData;` to `unsigned short *data = (unsigned short *)src->imageData;`
- `im.data[k*w*h + i*w + j] = data[i*step + j*c + k]/255.;` to `im.data[k*w*h + i*w + j] = data[i*step + j*c + k]/65536.;`

**What other modifications should I make to ensure yolo is training on 16 bit channels?** Thank you.

Comment: Were you able to move forward with 16 bit data? I was looking at (yolov3), and it expects rgb data. I added support to read in 16-bit .pgm grayscale files. However, if you set the channels=1, and load 16-bit data, comment out the call to rgbgr_image(), it will assert in distort_image during training as 3 channels are expected for distortion. Seemed like I was going down a rabbit hole.

Answer (score -1):

The detector seems to expect 3 channels (rgb). I was able to get it to train by also disabling the distortion augmentation, and updating the areas of the code that were hardcoded to 3 channels i.e load_data_seg(). In my case I was using opencv and loading 16-bit pgm files.